# select class static function based on type using template

Tags: c++, c++17

A template function returns the class's static function based on type. But how can I use an object as the parameter of which the type is deduced from?

```
class A {
 public:
  static funcA() {}
  static funcB() {}
  static funcC() {}
  ...
};

class B {
 public:
  static funcA() {}
  static funcB() {}
  static funcC() {}
  ...
};

using funcType = std::function<void()>

template<typename T>
funcType getfunByType(T t) {
   return T::funcA
}

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  // void* p = nullptr; ??
  bool s = false;
  if (s) {
    p = &a;
  } else {
    p = &b;
  }
  // funcType func = getfunByType(&p); ???
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you're asking about the `???` in comments: Static polymorphism and runtime type-erasure don't mix. If you really want the function that is called to depend on the runtime type of an object pointed to by a pointer, use a base class and a `virtual` function.

Comment: Sorry. What I want to do is to determine which object to be passed as the parameter to the getfunByType() function, A or B, based on a runtime variable s. But I can't find a way to do this, so in my question I used void* to express something like I want. Or it should be a std::any?

Comment: There's no way to do that using `void*`. If your types are limited to a small set, you could try using e.g. `std::variant<A, B>` and an appropriate call to `std::visit`

Comment: @alterigel is there any way to use template type deduction?

Comment: how many possible types (e.g. `A` and `B`) are you willing to support? If the set is relatively small, you can use `std::variant` and `std::visit` quite concisely and still have template argument deduction. If the set is large or likely to keep growing, just use a base class and `virtual` function instead and forget about template argumet deduction.